# How can I access properties on the state from an action?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to access information from the state from within an action. The state is an array of objects with an ID property.

Upon inspecting the variable `state.devices` within an action, I only see this:
[image: state.devices from an action]

Inspecting the same variable from within a mutator shows exactly what I want to see:
[image: state.devices from a mutator]

Here's a quick snippet exemplifying various attempts. Sorry, it is not runnable.

```js
const state = {
  devices: {}
};

const getters = {
  devices: state => state.devices || {}
};

const actions = {
  [DEVICE_EVENT_ACTION]: ({ commit }, event) => {

    // Attempt 0: exits prematurely
    let storedDevice0 = getters
      .devices(state)
      .find(d => d.deviceId === event.deviceId);

    // Attempt 1: exits prematurely
    let storedDevice1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.device)).find(
      x => x.deviceId === event.deviceId
    );
    
    // Attempt 2: exits prematurely
    let storedDevice2 = state.devices.find(x => x.deviceId === event.deviceId);

    // Attempt 3: exits prematurely
    let storedDevice3;
    for (let d in state.devices) {
      if (state.devices[d].deviceId === event.deviceId) {
        storedDevice3 = state.devices[d];
      }
    }

    console.log(storedDevice0); // nothing
    console.log(storedDevice1); // nothing
    console.log(storedDevice2); // nothing
    console.log(storedDevice3); // nothing
    
    commit(DEVICE_UPDATED, event);
  }
};

const mutations = {
  [DEVICE_UPDATED](state, event) {
    // Attempt 0
    let storedDevice0 = getters
      .devices(state)
      .find(d => d.deviceId === event.deviceId);

    // Attempt 1
    let storedDevice1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.devices)).find(
      x => x.deviceId === event.deviceId
    );

    // Attempt 2: 
    let storedDevice2 = state.devices.find(x => x.deviceId === event.deviceId);

    // Attempt 3
    let storedDevice3;
    for (let d in state.devices) {
      if (state.devices[d].deviceId === event.deviceId) {
        storedDevice3 = state.devices[d];
      }
    }

    console.log(storedDevice0); // works
    console.log(storedDevice1); // works
    console.log(storedDevice2); // works
    console.log(storedDevice3); // works
  }
};
```

I can't find anything mentioning this in the documentation. Why would it differ, and how can I access that state list property in the action? My logic behind this choice is that my actions can be more specific, which call a more generic "device update" mutator, which allows me to log and notify the user with pertinent data that doesn't exist in the state object, but does exist in the store's `device` array.

Comment: You don't pass in `state` in the one that doesn't work;  you pluck `{ commit }` out of it. You'll get the module-level `state`.

Comment: That was is, thank you. I knew it would be something I'd completely overlooked after having stared at this for far too long. If you want to answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'd chalk it up to a simple typo-class error; glad it's working. (Always check your assumptions :)